# Pass a flag from view to layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use my application layout for every page of my website, homepage included.

However in the homepage I don't want to display the top bar (which is part of the layout).

What's the proper way to pass a flag like `disable_topbar`**from the** homepage **view to the layout**?

I have already discarded the following solutions:

- `content_for`, because it is for markup
- `local_assigns`, because I can't use them since it is not the view that is rendering the layout (as would happen with a partial)
- instance variables? (they don't seem to be the right solution)

Comment: Why do you feel instance variables are not the right solution? You could always wrap one in two `disable_topbar!` and `disable_topbar?` helpers.

Comment: What @janfoeh said. You can set them in your controller action as needed to control the topbar display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the "top bar" into a partial (i.e. _header.html.erb) and then in the application.html.erb add something like:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/header" unless current_page?(root_url) %>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `current_page?`. It might be useful, thanks! However the suggested use of a partial is totally unrelated to the question ;)

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" way is to use `content_for`.

```
# layout.html.erb

<%= yield :topbar %>

<%# the default content for topbar %>
<% content_for :topbar do %>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>
```

---

```
# home.html.erb
<% content_for :topbar, flush: true do %>  
<% end %>
```

`flush:true` tells rails to replace any content it has captured. The default behaviour it to append to the buffer.

You want to avoid littering your views with assignments and conditionals as far as possible. Content for declares named blocks and any view which does not like the content provided by the layout overrides it in a declarative way. You can think of it as [**Tell don't ask**](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask)  for views.

Comment: Good point. However this solution would be unpractical in my case, since all my views have the top bar, but the homepage. It would be against DRY.

Comment: No, I think you have got it wrong - you would only need to override `content_for :topbar` in your home view.

Comment: You're right! But does it work? Isn't the :topbar content declared in the view always overwritten by the same declaration in the layout? If so your solution works only by adding another condition in the layout to check the presence of a custom topbar...

Comment: Sorry my example is a little bit off. I have edited it - and yes it does work. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html

Comment: note that I use `yield :topbar` and not ’<%= content_for(:topbar) %>’. `content_for(:foo).to_s` will dump whatever has been captured while yield waits for the other yeilds to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

By default almost every page will render topbar with one exception.

I will use haml syntax as I am more familiar with it than with erb. In your topbar.html.haml

One option is to use instance variables

```
unless @hide_topbar
  - here is topbar view code
```

`@hide_topbar` may be declared in your homepage action, or if it applies to all actions in this specific `controller` in its `before_filer`

//

Another option is to add `show_topbar?` method to your `ApplicationHelper` and within this method check current contorller and action names, but I would rather discourage you from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get max's answer to work.  However, I was able to achieve the desired result with the more typical approach:

```
# layout.html.erb
<% if content_for?(:topbar) %>
  <%= yield :topbar %>
<% else %>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  <ul>
<% end %>
```

Now if you flush the content in your home view the default topbar would be used, which is not what we want.  But you can just add a `display:none` div to achieve a "do nothing" result.  If using bootstrap:

```
# home.html.erb
<% content_for :topbar do %>
  <div class="d-none">
<% end %>
```